# How can I get the original image dimensions from an image loaded from rails in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails app with one of my friends, and I'm helping out with some frontend and UI tasks.  For one of the views, the page just displays an image that a user uploaded.

In my javascript, I need to get the image width which can possibly change every time.  In other questions on this site, I saw many people had the solution to use something like `var image = new Image();`  However, since this image is being dynamically loaded by rails, I cannot access the image like that.

Essentially, how can I determine the original dimensions of a dynamically loaded image in javascript?

Dirty solutions I have imagined but will try to avoid:

1- Get the item's width before modifying it with css - e.g.

```
originalWidth = img.width();
img.css('width','100%');
```

2- have the rails app store the image dimensions so I can embed them like `<%= @image.width%>` in my JS code

Comment: is the image in an `<img>` tag? Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see why you can't use the `new Image()` technique

Comment: Yes, it is.  The `src` is decided dynamically by rails, I may perhaps be missing something.  The `new Image()` technique was not working for me, but it's possible I made an error I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the image element has an id or some other identifier

```
img=new Image();
img.src=document.getElementById('imgElement').src;
console.log(img.width,img.height);
```

Comment: Oddly it's returning "0".  Could it be that I have to set up a special function to trigger once the image has fully loaded?  edit:  yep, that was the problem.

Comment: ah, yeah, image definitely has to be loaded :-)